# Meaning of "for your record"

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

What does the expression "for your record" mean here:

> "If you have any questions about the study, please ask us.  A copy of this form will be provided to you **for your record**."

The text is from a consent form for the study of the access to medical services in a poor village.

Comment: Normally the phrasing is "for your record**s**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically just "for you to keep in case you need to refer to it" — some people might like to keep a copy of something they've signed in case they need to reread it later.